# Ошибка при подключении к postgres через localhost python

Tags: python, postgresql, localhost, psycopg2

Столкнулся с проблемой, вчера пользовался postgres, сегодня появилась ошибка, при этом ничего не меняя

```
import psycopg2

psycopg2.connect(
    database="postgres",
    user="postgres",
    password="qwerty123",
    host="localhost",
    port=5432
)
```

Ошибка:     *conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "('localhost'" to address: Unknown host
could not translate host name ")" to address: Unknown host*

Comment: `host="127.0.0.1"` попробуйте

Answer (score 0):

Вы не поверите )

```py
psycopg2.connect('database=postgres user=postgres password=qwerty123 host=localhost port=5432')
```